# Pattern Searching in gorm rest API

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I want to fetch the name list on the basis of searching and sort lexicographically order.

I have used "like" keyword to get a similar search in the database, and I don't know how to get the required order.

```
func SearchByName(db *gorm.DB) func(c *gin.Context) {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        var uemail = c.Param("rexed")
        var rnex []resource
            //Param matches your regex //c.JSON(200,rnex)
            if err := db.Where("name LIKE ?", "%uemail%").Find(&rnex).Error; err!=nil{
                c.AbortWithStatus(404)
                fmt.Println(err)
            } else {
                c.JSON(200, rnex)
            }
    }
}
```

I am getting

> Mismatched *DB and string & Report incompatible types in binary and unary operation

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, to set the order, use the `.Order()` method on gorm

```golang
db.Where("name LIKE ?", "%uemail%").Order("name").Find(&rnex)
```

For the second part where you're getting the error, I don't have enough context from the code you posted, but my first thought is that you're trying to parse in a value that is the wrong type in your `resource` struct.

Comment: Thanks for that.but the uemail shows unused variable.

Comment: I changed rexed to name, as I am doing pattern search in name, but the uemail shows unused uemail variable.

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't notice, but that is not going to work like that, you need to do something like `Where("name LIKE ?", "%" + uemail + "%")`